# How to toggle add remove multiple items in an array at the same position?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify datatable. In that table I am adding which table header and data has to show. I has written some code related to remove or add items in an array. But it is not proper code. If I remove multiple headers they are removing. But if I add them again their order changing. Can anyone please help me.

Please go through the below link for the code in codepen

```
A full code can be found in
```

https://codepen.io/kiranvilla/pen/JVRvwg?editors=1010

Comment: Here the problem is you are not displaying table data dynamically. You should also check for display property before populating table row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing only the headers data when you apply the filter, and your table can be like this. You can add headers and data binding dynamically,

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-10"
    >
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td v-for="(head, index) in headers" :key="index">
          {{ props.item[head['value']] }}
        </td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dLpaOp?editors=1010

Comment: Great, that helped you :)